# How to generate multiple random numbers?

Tags: c++

At the moment, this program generates only one random number printed 3 times. How can I get it to print three different random numbers?

Also I'm surprised I didn't need the ctime header even though I used time(0).

```
//This program generates three random numbers.

#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using std::endl;
using std::cout;

int main() {
    unsigned number;

    srand(time(0));
    number = rand() % 10 + 1;

    cout << number << "         ";
    cout << number << "         ";
    cout << number << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you know about loops? And did you try calling `rand` more than once?

Comment: _"Also I'm surprised I didn't need the ctime header even though I used time(0)."_ It sometimes happens that such headers are already included by other standard headers implicitely. You should never rely about that though.

Answer (score 3):

> At the moment, this program generates only one random number printed 3 times. How can I get it to print three different random numbers?

You seem to have a heavy misconception what

> ```
> number = rand() % 10 + 1;
> ```

really does.

At the point you do that assignment

> ```
> rand() % 10 + 1
> ```

the value of `number` is evaluated and stored ***once*** to the variable from that mentioned line above.

Further accesses to `number` won't trigger that evaluation anymore.

---

If you want to do the evaluation everytime you access a specific *"variable"*, you might want to use a *lambda function* instead:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>

int main() {

    std::srand(std::time(nullptr));
    auto number = []() {
        return std::rand() % 10 + 1;
    };

    std::cout << number() << "         ";
    std::cout << number() << "         ";
    std::cout << number() << std::endl;
}
```

Here's a [live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6e243cf08c800ed0)

---

> Also I'm surprised I didn't need the ctime header even though I used `time(0)`.

It happens with specific compiler implementations that you're lucky and one of the already used standard headers already includes the required `ctime` header for the `time(0)` call.

The safe and portable way you should rather write

```
#include <ctime>

// ...
    std::time(nullptr)
// ...
```

Comment: I'm not sure I'd suggest lambdas to someone who doesn't yet completely understand how variable assignment works...maybe just a plain old vanilla function would be a little more friendly?

Comment: @scohe001 Well, some programming languages provide such _eval_ behavior. Maybe, the OP comes with such knowledge. So I can't see what's bad about clarifying the misconception and providing an actual equivalent in standard c++ language.

Answer (score 2):

You only set `number` once, it will continue to be the random number you have assigned to it until you assign something else to it, such as another random number from `rand()`

```
/This program generates three random numbers.

#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using std::endl;
using std::cout;

int main()

{
  unsigned number;

  srand(time(0));
  number = rand() % 10 + 1;  
  cout << number << "         ";

  number = rand() % 10 + 1;
  cout << number << "         ";

  number = rand() % 10 + 1;
  cout << number << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assignments in C++ are not formulas that are applied every time the variable is used.  So when you do this:

```
number = rand() % 10 + 1;
```

You assign a value to `number` **once**, at the point in the program where it appears.

If you want to get more random numbers, you need to call `rand` and assign to `number` multiple times.

```
number = rand() % 10 + 1;
cout << number << "         ";
number = rand() % 10 + 1;
cout << number << "         ";
number = rand() % 10 + 1;
cout << number << endl;
```

Comment: Well, the solution would work, but from context and (seemingly applied) concept, the OP probably expects something like a lambda funciton.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using std::endl;
using std::cout;

int main()

{
  unsigned number;

  srand(time(0));
  number = rand() % 10 + 1;
  cout << number << "         ";
  number = rand() % 10 + 1;
  cout << number << "         ";
  number = rand() % 10 + 1;
  cout << number << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

The reason why your code snippet returned the same random three times, is,

```
//This program generates three random numbers.

#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using std::endl;
using std::cout;

int main()

{
  unsigned number;

  srand(time(0));
  number = rand() % 10 + 1;

  cout << number << "         ";
  cout << number << "         ";
  cout << number << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Value of 'Random' is assigned to number only once, and it will remain constant until it is assigned again.

Hope you got me right ;)